# How to play an Mp3 file using its Path using Kotlin?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, uri, android-music-player

I started a project for making a music player.Initially i have Listed all mp3 files using ApI level 29.But i am facing the problem in creating a mediaplayer.Everytime the error is showing is "Found a null Uri"....I have tried this...
      fun getAppExternalFilesDir(): File? {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) { 
            getExternalFilesDir(null)
        } else { // @Deprecated in API 29.
            // /storage/emulated/0
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        }
    }

```
fun ListDir(f: File) {
    var files: Array<File>? = f.listFiles()
    list.clear()
    if (files != null) {
        for (file: File in files) {
            if (file.name.endsWith(".mp3")){
                list.add(Model(file.name))
            }


        }
    }
    listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long ->
        if (position>=0) {
            var textcopy: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.foldername)
            var namecopied: String = textcopy.text.toString()
            mediaplayer = MediaPlayer()
            var uri: Uri = Uri.parse((getAppExternalFilesDir().toString() + "/" + namecopied))
            Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri)
            mediaplayer.prepare()
            mediaplayer.start()
        }
          //where  getAppExternalFilesDir() =getExternalFilesDir(null)






    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not optimized as well, you can use cold sequences to search through files, it'll destroy older instances of file as it runs

```kotlin
fun ListDir(f: File) {
    val mp3Files = f.walk().map { it.absolutePath }.filter { it.endsWith(".mp3") }.toList()

    listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long ->
        if (position>=0) {
            ...
            var uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(File(mp3Files[position]))
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This will create proper Uri that you can pass to the media player to play the mp3 files.

Comment: showing two errors one with (File(mp3Files[position])) not considering position and other with  { it.name.endsWith(".mp3") } with error showing in name .

Comment: as you didnot take mp3files with an arraylist or other thing.i didnot able to recognize the mp3files val

Comment: @DikShU check the updated answer, this will do so, i checked this.

Comment: i updated the mp3files as ArrayList of strings but it.name still showing the error.  name.is not recngnized

Comment: still you not take mp3files as an array list.tried but showing errors

Comment: @DikShU toList() converts Sequence to ArrayList.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212480/discussion-between-animesh-sahu-and-dikshu).